# Pandas DataFrame manipulation from numerical into binary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
columns: a, b
entries: [[1,2],[3,2],[1,3]]
```

I want to transform it into a dataframe with max(a+b) columns such that every entry in the range(a,a+b) is an 1 and every other one is a 0. The example would look like this then:

```
columns: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
entires: [[1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0]]
```

Is there any easy way to do this in python, preferably with pandas? I can do it samplewise with a for loop but that is very time consuming and ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a new dataframe using `np.repeat` and `np.range`.

```
n = df.sum(1).max()
df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat([np.arange(1,n+1)], len(df), axis=0), columns=np.arange(1,n+1))
df_out = (df_out.ge(df.a, axis=0) & df_out.le(df.sum(1), axis=0)).astype(int)

Out[233]:
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  0
```

---

**Timing**:

Surprisingly, it is faster than `get_dummies` on dataframe with big number of rows.

Sample:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [190]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, range(x['a'], x['a'] + x['b'] + 1))), axis=1).str.get_dummies()
845 ms ± 3.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [244]: %%timeit
 ...: n = df.sum(1).max()
 ...: df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat([np.arange(1,n+1)], len(df), axis=0), columns=np.arange(1,n+1))
 ...: (df_out.ge(df.a, axis=0) & df_out.le(df.sum(1), axis=0)).astype(int)
 ...:
 ...:
3.35 ms ± 5.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

@Shubham solution:

In [240]: %%timeit
     ...: m = np.arange(1, df.max().sum())
     ...: a = np.tile(m, (len(df), 1))
     ...: pd.DataFrame((df.to_numpy()[:, 0, None] <= a) &
     ...:              (a <= df.sum(1).to_numpy()[:, None]), dtype='int', columns=m)
     ...:
1.79 ms ± 1.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Why not vectorize that `df_out.agg(lambda x: (x >= df.a.values) & (x <= df.sum(1))).astype(int)`?

Comment: Nice idea @Andy ..Can you please test my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

We can try `numpy` broadcasting:

```
m = np.arange(1, df.max().sum())
a = np.tile(m, (len(df), 1))

a = pd.DataFrame((df.to_numpy()[:, 0, None] <= a) & 
                 (a <= df.sum(1).to_numpy()[:, None]), dtype='int', columns=m)
```

Result:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: your is the fastest :) +1

Comment: Thanks for testing @AndyL ...liked your answer already upvoted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, range(x['a'], x['a'] + x['b'] + 1))), axis=1).str.get_dummies()
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, the only problem is that the columns are named 1, 10, 11,..., 2, 21,... Any solutions for that or should I do it by hand?